# Recibir datos mediante POST en PHP utilizando fetch JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

estoy intentando enviar datos mediante utilizando fetch a un servidor PHP el asunto es que no se como accedo desde PHP a dicha propiedad, aquí dejo mi código
JS:

```
function obtenerDatosSuma(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    //ALMACENAR LOS DATOS DEL FORMULARIO

    var mes = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var cant_archivos = document.getElementById("archivos_input").value;
    var num_celda = document.getElementById("celda_num").value;


    var data2 = {

            mes: mes,
            num_archivos: cant_archivos,
            numero_celd: num_celda
    };



    fetch('http://localhost/PHP/controller/pruebaFetch.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data2 
    })
    .then(function(data){

        return data.json();
    })
    .then(myJson => { 

        console.log(myJson);

    });

}
```

Pero desde PHP estoy intentando acceder a ello con esto:

```
$datos = $_POST['data2'];
```

Esto me lanza el error de que no esta definido `data2`

> Notice: Undefined index: data2 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\controller\pruebaFetch.php on line 3

La verdad no tengo idea de como se recogen los datos.

**EDIT: Aqui mi codigo `HTML`**

```
<form action="../controller/CalcularValor.php" method="post" id="form-suma" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="selector">MES</label>
            <select name="selector" id="selector" class="form-control">
                <option value="ENERO">ENERO</option>
                <option value="FEBRERO">FEBRERO</option>
                <option value="MARZO">MARZO</option>
                <option value="ABRIL">ABRIL</option>
                <option value="MAYO">MAYO</option>
                <option value="JUNIO">JUNIO</option>
                <option value="JULIO">JULIO</option>
                <option value="AGOSTO">AGOSTO</option>
                <option value="SEPTIEMBRE">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
                <option value="OCTUBRE">OCTUBRE</option>
                <option value="NOVIEMBRE">NOVIEMBRE</option>
                <option value="DICIEMBRE">DICIEMBRE</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="archivos_input">Numero de archivos</label>
            <input type="number" name="archivos_input" id="archivos_input" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <label for="celda_num">NUMERO DE CELDA(Ej: A35)</label>
            <input type="text" name="celda_num" id="celda_num" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_calcular">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te comento que lo puedes hacer de este modo, mediante el uso de [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)

Aquí accedes a los valores directo desde el `form` de tu página web

```
let formulario = new FormData(document.getElementById("iddetuformulario"))
```

Posterior puedes construir tu envio de datos con *Fetch* de este modo, donde como segundo argumento a la función le pasas la *key* `method` para indicar que tipo de verbo HTTP será, asì como en la etiqueta *body* el value `formulario`

```
fetch('http://localhost/PHP/controller/pruebaFetch.php', {
     method: "post",
     body: formulario
}).then((response) => {
     /*acciones a realizar*/     
}).then((data) => {
     /*mas acciones a realizar*/
})
```

De tal modo que puedas acceder a los elementos en PHP de este modo

```
$datos = $_POST['data2'];
```

**Aclaración**

Como estamos accediendo directamete al `form` por medio de su id, entonces no hay necesidad de declarar una variable distinta para capturar cada input que tiene el mismo dentro de si; es decir solo debes tener una variable con la cual lo accedas y después en tu petición `fetch` hagas `body: data`

Una vez hecho lo anterior, desde PHP accedes pero por medio de su atributo name, es decir

```
//debe ser de este modo
$dato = $_POST['name1'];
```

Comment: Hola @alfa p, gracias por el aporte, mucho mas fácil utilizando FormData. He probado tu respuesta y he intentado almacenar el valor enviado desde el formulario, y me da error de variable no definida, estoy intentando acceder desde PHP con $datos = $_POST['archivos_input']; archivos_input corresponde a el ID de un input en el HTML, voy a editar la pregunta para que le eches un vistazo al HTML

Comment: @BrianHernandez recuerda que desde PHP no accedes a los inputs mediante su id sino mediante la etiqueta name, revisa la explicación que agregué al final de mi respuesta

Comment: Efectivamente! muchas gracias grande por corregir mi error y mis dudas. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que mandarlo serializado

```
fetch('http://localhost/PHP/controller/pruebaFetch.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({data2: data2}) 
    })
```

Y desserializarlo en php

```
$datos = json_decode($_POST['data2'], true);
```

$datos puede ser false o un array asociativo.

Comment: Hola, Me lanza un error de sintaxis Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Perdona, eran llaves y no corchetes

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria asi, envio un **array** y una **variable normal:**

En el JAVASCRIPT:

```
var data2 = {
  mes: '23-05-2022',
  num_archivos: 560,
  numero_celd: 23
};

fetch('http://localhost/PHP/controller/pruebaFetch.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({'mi_dato_1':data2, 'mi_dato_2':'Hola', }) ,
}).then(function(data){
   return data.json();
}).then(myJson => { 
   console.log(myJson);
});
```

En mi PHP:

```
$_post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

//este es un array
$array_pago_contador = $_post["mi_dato_1"];

//este es una variable normal
$estado_envio_contador = $_post["mi_dato_2"];
```