# Tomar el valor de un select para poder trabajar con él

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando hacer algo muy simple pero no soy capaz. Necesito un formulario en el que pondré un select (este toma sus datos de un listado de post, pero eso no es relevante y funciona) y que ese valor seleccionado me lo devuelva para poder trabajar con él.

He leído muchas de sus aportaciones a preguntas similares pero no logro adaptarlas y que funcione. Sé que no trabaja en el mismo lugar el php que el javascript y que tengo que pasar la variable de una a otra.

Les paso código con diferentes opciones que he puesto y sin que funcionen. Lo único que me devuelve de forma correcta es el alert.

```
<form method="get" action="#" > 
    <select name="filtro_localidad"  id="filtro_localidad">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Selecciona una localidad</option>
        
    <?php
    foreach ( $last_posts as $post ) :
     setup_postdata( $post );?>
             
        <?php       
            $localidad = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'_localidad', true );
            
        ?>
            if ($localidad){
                <option value='<?php $localidad; ?>'><?php echo $localidad; ?></option>
            }
    

    <?php endforeach;?>
    
    </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" onclick="ShowSelected()"> 

</form>
```

Y la parte del script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var localidad_filtro='';
    function ShowSelected()
    {
        /* Para obtener el valor */ 
        var combo = document.getElementById("filtro_localidad");
        var localidad_filtro = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
                
            
        alert (localidad_filtro);

    }   
</script>
```

Para visualizar el resultado lo he intentado de diferentes formas y sólo el `alert()` me lo muestra y bien.

```
<?php       
    echo "select: ".$_GET['filtro_localidad'];

    echo "<script>document.write(localidad_filtro)</script>";       
?>
```

Todo este código está dentro de un mismo archivo **`.php`**.

Agradeceré mucho su ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Has probado hacer un [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) hacia el script que recoge esos valores?

Comment: No, no lo he probado ni usado nunca. He mirado documentación pero no entiendo bien como encajarlo en mi código

Comment: Quizás [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/245956/7014) te ayude.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente con el valor una vez seleccionado? El problema principal creo yo es que estás mezclando entornos: PHP funciona del lado del servidor y Javascript del lado del cliente. **Una vez estás en el cliente (Javascript), sólo tendrías que ir al servidor (PHP) si necesitas algo que no tengas en el cliente**. Lo digo por esto: `echo "select: ".$_GET['filtro_localidad'];` ¿Qué es lo que pretendes hacer ahí?

Comment: Entiendo que estoy en entorno diferentes y creo que el problema es ese, cómo pasar de uno a otro. Con ese echo sólo quería saber si recuperaba por GET el valor que necesitaba. Ya he visto que no

Answer (score 1):

Como algunos han mencionado en los comentarios, el problema es que estás mezclando entornos.

Una vez cargas todo del servidor y estás en JS, obtienes tu valor (hasta ahí, todo va bien).

Ahora, si lo que necesitas es usar ese valor en el servidor tienes que enviar un *request* desde el cliente de alguna forma. Una forma fácil de hacerlo sería dentro del url. Por ejemplo (usando tu código JS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var localidad_filtro='';
    function ShowSelected()
    {
        /* Para obtener el valor */ 
        var combo = document.getElementById("filtro_localidad");
        var localidad_filtro = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
                
        /* Hacer un request al servidor usando el valor */ 
        const new_url = "*la url actual*" + "?localidad=localidad_filtro";
        window.location.href = new_url;
    }   
</script>
```

Luego de cargar este nuevo *request* tendrás acceso al valor en el entorno PHP, y puedes accederlo con  `$_GET["localidad"]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aclarado